# Search, Match & Return location using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I am looking for an excel forumla that will search the text in a cell and return the location specified in an additional sheet if a match is found.

I have a sheet with the following columns

```
| item   | location   | numbers |
|--------|------------|---------|
| apple  | washington | 1234    |
| pear   | wisconsin  | 567     |
| orange | california | 890     |
```

And another sheet with the following columns:

```
| item_name           | location |
|---------------------|----------|
| super juicy pears   |          |
| fresh golden apples |          |
| apples from wa      |          |
```

What I want to do is search the text and display the location. Assume each fruit only has one state.

Note that I looked around on here and only found an unanswered question found here:

[Excel Match & Return Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156831/excel-match-return-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google sheets try:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,REGEXMATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4)),1,1)`

- `Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4` is location
- `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4` is item

**Edit**
To make search case insensitive:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,REGEXMATCH(A2,"(?i)"&Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4)),1,1)`

Comment: Quick question: looks like this is case sensitive and Apple doesnt match with apple. Any way to account for this without adding two entries to the fruit sheet?

Comment: Add `"(?i)"`  to regex to make it case insensitive

Comment: I hate to ask but where would I add this?

Comment: My second formula in the answer